# Unable to animate DOM element in codepen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to simply animate a shape every x milliseconds. I'm doing this in [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/dtturcotte/pen/ojPZdj).

I tried moving it using:

JavaScript:

- `ball.getBoundingClientRect().left += 100 + 'px'`
- `ball.style.left += 100 + 'px'`

jQuery:

- `$('#ball').position().left += 100 + 'px'`

But nothing seemed to work. The ball appears, but does not move. The timeout is being called as well. No errors in console are being thrown.

```
var ball = null;
var ball_x = null;
var ball_y = null;

function doMove() {
  ball.style.left += 100 + 'px';
  setTimeout(doMove,100); 
}

function init() {
  ball = document.getElementById('ball');
  ball_x = ball.getBoundingClientRect().left; //displays correct location
  ball_y = ball.getBoundingClientRect().top; //displays correct location

  doMove();
}

window.onload = init;
```

CSS:

```
#ball {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 200px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
  <div id='ball'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is *codepen* URL ?

Comment: @RayonDabre see above

Comment: `getBoundingClientRect()` is read-only property..

Comment: @RayonDabre then what about the other two methods I've tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `left` css returns a text like `100px`  value not a numerical one so that won't work. So using `+=` with it does a string concatenation not a numeric one creating a invalid value

[getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) returns a read-only object, so changing its properties don't have an effect

> The returned value is a DOMRect object, which contains read-only left,
>   top, right and bottom properties describing the border-box in pixels.
>   top and left are relative to the top-left of the viewport.

```js
var ball = null;

function doMove() {
  ball.style.left = ((parseInt(ball.style.left) || 0) + 100) + 'px'
  setTimeout(doMove, 2000);
}

function init() {
  ball = document.getElementById('ball');

  doMove();
}

window.onload = init;
```

```css
#ball {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 200px;
  transition: left 2s;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id='ball'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: So quick and accurate! #RESPECT